# MYSQL query optimization question using Count and 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count

I have 2 tables **hjudges** and **hentry**

The hjudges table shows each eventid, category, timeofday, date

```
jeid (primary) | jcategory | jtimeofday | jedate

    101 |beginner    |AM|2020-01-01|
    101 |intermediate|AM|2020-01-01|
    101 |advanced    |AM|2020-01-01|
    102 |beginner    |AM|2020-01-05|
    102 |intermediate|AM|2020-01-05|
    102 |advanced    |AM|2020-01-05|
```

the hentry table show the users that have "entered" that event.  ( left some info off to make it easier)

```
hentryid (primary)|heid | hcategory | htimeofday | hedate | huserid | hstatus | hedtime

1| 101 | beginner     |AM|2020-01-01| 5 |active | 2019-12-05 12:00:00
2| 101 | intermediate |AM|2020-01-01| 5 |active | 2019-12-05 12:00:00
3| 101 | beginner     |AM|2020-01-01| 6 |active | 2019-12-05 12:00:00
4| 101 | intermediate |AM|2020-01-01| 6 |active | 2019-12-05 12:00:00
```

because events are limited, as people enter I want to count the entries.

the following query WORKS, but is very slow.  It takes 9 seconds or more to do this.

```
select 
ei.jcategory as jcategory, 
ei.jtimeofday  as jtimeofday , 
ei.jedate as jedate,
(select count(*) from hentry  e where e.heid =ei.jeid  and e.hcategory = ei.jcategory and ei.jedate = e.hedate and ei.jtimeofday = e.htimeofday 
and (((e.hstatus = 'pending' or e.hstatus = 'npending') and e.hedtime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND) and e.huserid <> '5' ) OR (e.hstatus = 'active')) ) as count 
from hjudges  ei where ei.jeid  = '101' 
group by ei.jedate, ei.jtimeofday, ei.jcategory
```

Below is the result, but can take a long time depending on the query.

```
jcategory   |jtimeofday|jedate    | count    
 beginner   |AM        |2020-01-01| 2
intermediate|AM        |2020-01-01| 2
advanced    |AM        |2020-01-01| 0
```

I was able to create some alternative  join queries, but either it would not count correctly or not show 0 for the advanced level. Because there were not any entries in the entry table.

Need some help.

Comment: shiw an EXPLAIN of your query and show also the create tables of bith to see where your indexes are

Comment: I mistyped the result.  I want the result to show the counted entries and not create a "table".  Sorry about that .  I have the id's indexed in the 2 tables.

Comment: We recently moved to a different server. When someone enters I put them in the hentry table as pending and then count all the entries depending on their status and time they entered.  (alot of people will try to enter at the same time) this is why time interval is critical.  I have primary listed on the 2 tables, but no indexes.  Is that the possible problem?? to Index the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you attempt to JOIN the tables rather than doing an subquery for count like so:

```
SELECT ei.jcategory AS jcategory,
       ei.jtimeofday AS jtimeofday ,
       ei.jedate AS jedate,
       count(*)
FROM hjudges ei
LEFT JOIN hentry e on e.heid =ei.jeid
    AND e.hcategory = ei.jcategory
    AND ei.jedate = e.hedate
    AND ei.jtimeofday = e.htimeofday
    AND (e.hstatus = 'active'
        OR
        (e.hstatus in ('pending', 'npending') AND e.hedtime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND) AND e.huserid <> '5'))
    AND ei.jeid = '101'
GROUP BY ei.jedate,
         ei.jtimeofday,
         ei.jcategory
```

Also create an index on hstatus, hedtime and huserid and then run the query. There are other ways to tackle this as well such as splitting the query into two. I would have added this in comment if query was short.

## Giving MySQL hint to use an index of your choice

When you do an `explain select...` like `nbk` suggested, MySQL will tell you the indexes being used. You can provide the query a hint to use a different index than the one it is choosing. For that, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html.

## Splitting the queries

You could split the query into 2 - one with hstatus of active and the other with other hstatuses.

```
select jcategory, jtimeofday, jedate, sum(totals)
from
(
    SELECT ei.jcategory AS jcategory,
           ei.jtimeofday AS jtimeofday ,
           ei.jedate AS jedate,
           count(*) as totals
    FROM hjudges ei
    LEFT JOIN hentry e on e.heid =ei.jeid
        AND e.hcategory = ei.jcategory
        AND ei.jedate = e.hedate
        AND ei.jtimeofday = e.htimeofday
        AND e.hstatus = 'active'
        AND ei.jeid = '101'
    GROUP BY ei.jedate,
             ei.jtimeofday,
             ei.jcategory

    union all

    SELECT ei.jcategory AS jcategory,
           ei.jtimeofday AS jtimeofday ,
           ei.jedate AS jedate,
           count(*) as totals
    FROM hjudges ei
    LEFT JOIN hentry e on e.heid =ei.jeid
        AND e.hcategory = ei.jcategory
        AND ei.jedate = e.hedate
        AND ei.jtimeofday = e.htimeofday
        AND e.hstatus in ('pending', 'npending')
        AND e.hedtime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND)
        AND e.huserid <> '5'
        AND ei.jeid = '101'
    GROUP BY ei.jedate,
             ei.jtimeofday,
             ei.jcategory
) x
group by jcategory, jtimeofday, jedate
```

This will allow you to comment out one of the two queries to study performance individually and find out which one is the bottleneck and why, and what kind of indexes to put in place for it to run faster.

Comment: it took longer.  Now I understand what he meant.  I only have primary keys on the tables. I ran the explain select and below is the information :::   ID 1
select type PRIMARY ei 
Partitions  NULL
type ALL 
 possible_keys   NULL
key    NULL
key_len    NULL
ref    NULL
rows 10231
filtered 10.00
Extra Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 
ID 2
select type DEPENDENT SUBQUERY e 
 partitions   NULL
type ALL 
  possible keys  NULL
key   NULL
key_len   NULL
ref NULL
rows 159495
filtered 0.00
extra Using where

Comment: I've heard indexing can also slow down inserts and I need the fast inserts.  I tried various joins, but came up not showing 0  for no entries.

Comment: @H.L. You will need indexes for faster querying. Yes, indexes can slow down inserts/updates/deletes but it's all a balancing act. Try adding an index as I recommended and see if slowdown of inserts/updates/deletes is noticeable at all. If your `select` speeds up significantly without noticeable difference in inserts/updates/deletes, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Did the answer above help you? @H.L.

Comment: Yes, it did.  I also when through and changed some of the coding on the page as well. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Awesome. Very well done, @H.L. You are welcome to wait for more answers, or if you feel like it you can put closure to your question by marking this one as accepted. Totally your choice. Thank you!